# Test a function throwing an Exception in a Task in xunit

Tags: c#, xunit

I want to test using xunit a function that run a task and throw in a that task
For example :

```
public void doSomething(){
     Task.Run(() =>
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            });
}
```

When I want to test this function by doing this :

```
[Fact]
public void TestIfTheMethodThrow()
{
   Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => doSomething()); // should return true but return false                                                                   
}
```

I want that the Task.Run() finish completely then the assert can be done. anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising and handling exceptions using TPL (the Tasks library) is slightly different, than the "standard" exception handling.
It is meaningful to evaluate only a completed task, so you need to wait for the completion, even if in this case it is an exception.

Have a look at this MSDN article [Exception handling (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library).

You have two different options:

- add `.Wait()` to the Task.Run(...)`

  ```
  Task.Run(() =>
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException();
         }).Wait();
  ```
- or wait while the task is completed `while(!task.IsCompleted) {}`

```
     var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            });
    while(!task.IsCompleted) {}
```

The test result should be then as expected - an exception is thrown.

It could be, that before the `Wait` your test has passed sporadically - don't be irritated - in this case the task execution was faster than the test check - this is a dangerous source of subtle errors.

Comment: Thanks you for you answers, What is the good way to not block the main thread ? Because writing a .Wait() block the caller of the method. should I use a "double" Task.Run() ? It is a proper way ?

Comment: Personaly, I think that wrapping a task in a task (only that the test works properly) is not a correct solution. You can either change your test strategy resp. program model or use async/await (as @Jefferson Raposo suggested).

Answer (score 2):

You can write your method using `async` and `await`

Read this for reference [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

The new method look like this, and the caller will decide if want wait or not, if you call with `await` it will wait the task complete, otherwise it will continue without wait the task completion

```cs
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    if (true)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    await FooAsync();
}
```

In the test:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task TestIfTheMethodThrow()
{
   await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => DoSomethingAsync());                
}
```